# Is this FindAllPath algorithm correct in a directed graph?

Tags: computer-science, graph-algorithm

I was looking for an algorithm to print all possible paths between two nodes in a directed graph .

I saw this :

```
    procedure FindAllPaths(u, dest)
{
   push u to stack;
   if(u == dest)
   {
      print stack;
   }
   else
   {
      foreach v that is adjacent with u and not in stack now
      {
         FindAllPaths(v, dest);
      }
   }
   pop from stack;
}
```

but when I run it , It prints a correct path and get in an infinite loop and prints that paths !!
What's the problem ?

Special Thanks,

Comment: Could you post your actual code too?

Comment: yes , but  is this algorithm correct ?

Comment: Yes, I think it is. What do you mean by `get in an infinite loop and prints that paths`?

Comment: It prinst a correct path but get in a loop and prints that path.

Comment: Your `foreach v that is adjacent with u and not in stack now` may not be implemented correctly. It sounds like the loop is accessing the same `v` an infinite number of times.

Comment: No , I'm sure it is ok , but i'm not sure about the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JavaScript implementation of your algorithm, with an example graph. It works here. Please post more information if you see a difference with your implementation:

```
var edges = [
    {from:0, to:0},
    {from:0, to:1},
    {from:0, to:2},
    {from:1, to:3},
    {from:2, to:3},
    {from:2, to:0}
];

var stack = [];

function FindAllPaths(u, dest) {
    stack.push(u);
    if(u === dest)
    {
        console.log(stack.join('->'));
    }
    else
    {
        for(i in edges) {
            var edge = edges[i];
            if (edge.from == u && stack.indexOf(edge.to) < 0) {
                FindAllPaths(edge.to, dest);
            }
        }
    }
    stack.pop();
}

FindAllPaths(0, 3);
```